# Let $f(x)= (\sin x)^x$ Find $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm not sure if I derived it right. So, Let $f(x)$ = $(\sin x)^x$. $f' = x(\cos x)$ right? then just substitute so $f' = \frac{\pi}{2}(\cos\frac{\pi}{2})$ ? Since $\cos(180°)$ is equal to $-1$. Then its -$\frac{\pi}{2}$? they said it's wrong.

after reading all the comments I arrived with $f'$ = $(\sin x)^x$ $\frac{\sin x\ln(\sin x) + x\cos x}{\sin x}$ then substitute $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to x so that's $90 \deg$ $\cos90$ is $0$ and $\sin90\deg$ is $1$ so $1$ raised to $90\deg$ then $\frac {(1)(1)+0}{1}$ my final answer is now $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is in the multiple choice. But is it correct?

Comment: Is this function differentiable? Isn't the function discontinuous at 0?

Comment: @kart I'm  not I just answered this in a quiz and I got zero. I just applied the log. differentiation then substitute $90deg.$ to all x

Answer (score 4):

Given that the problem asks for the value of $f'$ at a *specific* point, rather than for a general formula for $f'$, we might look for a simple solution involving geometry, rather than differentiation rules.

Note that $0\leq\sin(x)\leq1$ on $[0,\pi]$, thus $f(x)=(\sin(x))^x$ is also between $0$ and $1$ on that interval. Furthermore, $f(\pi/2) = 1$.  Thus, $f$ has a maximum at $\pi/2$ so that $f'(\pi/2)=0$.

---

Admittedly, I came up with this explanation *after* noticing that the answer was zero.  Such a simple answer, though, only begs the question further - namely, is there a simple geometric explanation.

Answer (score 3):

- **Hint.** Take $\log$ and then work. Please see [Logarithmic Differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation).

Comment: Try to avoid _link only_ answers :)

Comment: @TheGame That is a hint for the answer so that the OP can work on it.

Comment: @s.c. so the answer is $f'$ = $\frac{xcosxsinx^x}{sinx}$ ?

Comment: @TheGame: it is not simply a link, it is suggested to take the log and even if you don't follow the link, differentiation is indicated.

Comment: @S.C.: when giving a hint, it is a good idea to explicitly state that so that others know it is a hint. Hints seem to be judged differently than full answers.

Comment: @robjohn Sure rob. Shall remember it from next time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

No, $f'(x)$ is not $x\cos x$. To find $f'$, first take natural logarithm of both sides of the definition of $f$:
$$
\ln(f(x)) = \ln\left((\sin x)^x\right)=x\ln(\sin x)
$$
Then take the derivative of both sides of the above equation. The left side becomes $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{(\sin x)^x}$, so this allows you to solve for what $f'(x)$ is.

Comment: What if $\sin x < 0$ ?

Comment: so the answer is $f'$ = $\frac{xcosxsinx^x}{sinx}$ ?

Comment: @Mickey Not quite. I think you made a mistake computing the derivative of the right hand side, $x\ln\sin x$. Be careful in your use of product rule/chain rule.

Comment: @ZhenZhang $f(x)$ is not a real-valued function when $\sin x<0$; for example, $f(-1/2)=1/\sqrt{\sin(-1/2)}$ is not real. In these cases, the method still works, but you have to use a complex branch of $\log$.

Comment: @mike hmm um i think this is it $f'$ = $(sinx)^x$ $\frac{sinxln(sinx)+xcosx}{sinx}$ product rule my bad

Comment: @Mickey [I believe you are right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%28sin+x%29%5Ex)

Comment: @mike can you help me out subsituting? i think its 1? since $cos90deg.$ is 0 and $sinx$ is 1?

Answer (score 2):

$ f'(x) = xsin(x)^{x-1}*cos(x) + (sin(x))^{x}*ln(sin(x))$
Now $f'(pi/2)$ is the limit as x goes to 0 of $f'(x)$. The first term is 0 and $sin(x)^{x}$ is 1 when x approaches 0. Therefore $f'(pi/2)$ is lim as x -> 0 of $ln(sin(x))$ which is $-\infty$.

Comment: [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $f(x)=\sin(x)^x$ note that $\ln|f(x)|=x\ln|\sin(x)|$ (the absolute values solve negativity problems) and the derivative of this is
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln|\sin(x)|+\frac {x\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Plugging in $x=\frac\pi2$, we get
$$f'\left(\frac\pi2\right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $f(x)=(\sin(x))^x=e^{x\ln(\sin(x))}$ thus we get
$f'(x)=e^{x\ln(\sin(x))}(\ln(\sin(x))+x\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)})$

Comment: $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$

Comment: [Oh, that's not right](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXnJELh78qs)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: it is right, take the logarithm of both sides

Comment: $(\sin(x))^x=e^{x\log(\sin(x))}$

Comment: yes i know what you mean i forgott the $\ln$ function

Comment: yes i have corrected it

Comment: I didn't downvote, so you'll need to see if those who did see the correction.